# Which is the fundamental group of $\mathbb{R}^2-\{(0,0),(0,1)\}?$

Tags: fundamental-groups

Which is the fundamental group of $\mathbb{R}^2-\{(0,0),(0,1)\}?$

Making a picture of this space with two closed curves with point basis on $(-1,0)$ and both disjoint each one involving $(0,0)$ and $(0,1)$, I can see that these curves are not homotopic. Even more, they are not contractible to a point. So my group has two classes of equivalence plus the constant curve, that are not homotopic of none of these curves. Then, can I afirme that this fundamental group is $\mathbb{Z}_3?$

Comment: It looks more like the free group on two generators... not  finite and ceratinly not abelian.

Comment: So, you are saying that if $\alpha$ and  $\beta$ are such curves, then $\pi_1(X,(-1,0) = F(\alpha,\beta)$, denoting $F$ de free group generated by such curves? Is this?? @DonAntonio Why?

Comment: Yes, that's what I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your space is homotopically equivalent to the double circle. Just like how $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{0\}$ is homotopically equivalent to the circle. As a result, the fundamental group is $\mathbb{Z}\coprod\mathbb{Z} $, the nonabelian coproduct of $\mathbb{Z}$ with itself.

Comment: By "coproduct" do you mean the *free product*?

Comment: I've seen free product denoted as $*$ so $\Bbb Z*\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Yes! That is indeed what I mean. But I like saying coproduct as that is the coproduct in the category of groups.

Comment: I cannot be sure as I don't know category theory (and you don't want to know what I think, in general, of it...), but take into account that $\;\Bbb Z*\Bbb Z=F(a,b)\;$ , and we get again the free group in two generators.